# Best way to extract all the props from a types whose props are conditional types in a generic function with a specified type

Tags: typescript, templates, generics, metaprogramming, typescript-generics

I have a extraction type called

```
type ExtractProps<T, K> = { [C in keyof T]:T[C] extends K ? K: never }
```

I have a type that I'm trying to extract from.

```
type FormRelation<T> = {
  [C in keyof T]: T[C] extends string ? FormField : FormFieldGroup
}
```

The parameter is also a `FormRelation`.

This type should extract only the specified K type from T. It does extract it, however this type fails in a parameter that should work.

```
FormRelation<T>[K] extends FormField ? FormField : never is not assignable to type T[K] extends string ? FormField : FormFieldGroup
```

`never` is considered a bottom type in typescript, therefore it shouldn't hold any value. That means the the compiler should ignore props with `never` type since it doesn't hold a value. However, it doesn't, meaning that this must be an intended feature. What are some work around to extract property from an object with specified types?

**New Update**

So I I've looked online and found a solution

```
type ExtractProps<T, TProps extends T[keyof T]> = Pick<T, ExtractPropsKey<T, TProps>>;

type ExtractPropsKey<T, TProps extends T[keyof T]> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends TProps ? P : never;
}[keyof T];
```

The types works, however my run-time function doesn't accept `class FormField` since it doesn't extend `T[keyof T]`, even though FormField is a possible type of the `FormRelation` Props.

Is there any possible way to extract all generic conditional type into a single union type??

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=44&ssc=10&pln=44&pc=13#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbAAqIPZgM4A8AKgDRRFa55QQIQB2AJtUQNoDWEI2AZuQLoA+KAF4oGAJap2xMvCRpMOfAGkus8pXyDBAbgBQ+0JFgIU6LXjUgNFZdVrAGzchy68BwsQG99UKKwYUBL0UJzcfET8AFyuGPw0dEwsllAA-OJQsfQQAG4QiAYAvm4RAgZG4NAAYtiIALYAShAANsjAEtj0xF5Qvv6sAMLBoeEeUbFsgwmOztQAFHhIIQDmUAA+UABG2NgtEMihm-QArvVbBRtQJ0wQPCEQjFenLS1XeCDnewCU6VC1DWqElaT1iAPqQJBAHEcCcwPoioYQk5EDw0NBBohHhJgINkIgnv1-FBTucCtkzhdCn5iahcrkKWTqcTEmAALJdYAAC0ZVIMLNoYAAmgdELyCsUkfQUWjUNB4Mh6mB9n0af56IqILElohVvzaahYpjsbj8YxJfpUG08NRwZCWoSoEUKlbkDb-nUIcCHTDsHC+k6KoK6sAoDwbuhOqFHOZgMREk5kgHWHBtct6CsYlBDiAnWQVAm5q4xpEhPMadgtgArCDoSYkGlgexEKp4WLeEkQADuUHmADoB7lkC0Tlrs-QQN9YgWSvx9FPTAoLPYNCphETUF0liSAPLV2I50R9Z00vc19B98J4eaV8-Ab59nh1GBoLnzcKiddqsN1Xv7UMSEeAAMujBFABBQE2VAtpAeB9vsGbcqBEgANQob8RIspu9DbqgJyIDB0BiFB+CEXgrASPw+oshIfA3tWtbAKUCQhEshxyh4eEEVUGHfiy9BnsxR63oxzHUSy2xYsg7Dif4iIsvJTrfPqWLAPhoQCdWFrhvQkZdFAiA3D08wkW2HoNM0bQdF0PS8f42HbvcILUGIMaKCZ9hkKwdreow-DKQihhAA)

Comment: You should post a full preferably self contained example of the issue you are having .. otherwise this is just too vague

Comment: I've just added more details about the type I'm trying to extract from and the parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

So I've just resorted to overloading the extract function to take in an expected return type.

```
declare function extract<T>(object: {[x: string]: any}, propTypes: {new(...values: any): any}): T
```

I'm pretty sure the compiler cannot extract specific conditional type if it the generic isn't specified. I'm still going to keep the previous generic type since it works perfectly fine on any type that don't have conditional types and both specified and unspecified type parameters.

This isn't a perfect solution, so if anybody has a better one feel free to place it down.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "generic conditional type" scares me.  If a conditional type depends on an unspecified generic type parameter, as inside the implementation of `run()`, the TypeScript compiler is not able to do very much type analysis on it.  It mostly defers analysis and cannot confirm that any value is assignable to it.

If the type parameter were specified, the compiler could evaluate the conditional type fully and understand, for example, that `ExtractProps<{a: string, b: number}, number>` is `{b: number}`.  But `ExtractProps<T, number>` for an unspecified generic `T` is a mystery.  The compiler does not understand that you could assign any property from that type to a variable of type `number`.

I tend to think of generic conditional types as something only useful to those who can specify the generic type parameter.  In the case of a generic function like `run()`, this means it's only useful to the *callers* of that function.  The implementation should avoid such types.  One way to have a function implementation use a different type signature from callers by making it an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function, like this:

```
function run<T>(props: FormRelation<T>): void;
function run(props: Record<string, FormField | FormFieldGroup>) {
  const fields = extract(props, [FormField]);
}
```

Here, callers of `run()` can specify the generic `T`, while the implementation just sees `props` as `Record<string, FormField | FormFieldgroup>`, a wider concrete type.  Then `fields` will work without error.  Or rather, it will compile without warning.  But the type will be useless to you with your definition of `extract()`.  If you only plan to use `extract()` inside of `run()`, then I'd suggest giving it a signature like this instead of your current one:

```
declare function extract<V>(
  object: object,
  propsTypes: { new(...value: any): V }[]
): Record<string, V>
```

This produces something known to have `V` values as its properties. Yes, it would forget about the particular keys of `object`, but inside the implementation of `run()` you can't possibly know those anyway, so there's no point in making `extract()` try to maintain those.  The only thing the implementation of `run()` should care about is that `extract(props, [FormField])` should be something whose properties are all `FormField`, and that's what this `extract()` does.

---

So that's where I'd suggest going.  There are other issues with your example code that I'll mention here, although they hopefully do not apply to your full code base:

- Your `FormField` and `FormFieldGroup` classes are structurally identical because they're both empty.  [That's a bad idea, even for example code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  Assuming you want the compiler to see that the `FormField` and `FormFieldGroup` types are different, you should give them differing structures.
- The function signature `function run<T>(props: FormRelation<T>): void;` is not particularly useful.  Usually generic functions are most user-friendly if the compiler can infer the type parameter instead of requiring the user to specify it manually.  But in this signature, there's no way to infer `T` from the type of `props`.  `FormRelation<T>` is lossy; the type of `props` has to look like `{a: FormField, b: FormFieldGroup, c: FormField}` or something, and there's no way to reverse-engineer that into a type like `{a: string, b: number[], c: boolean}`.  So the only way to get `T` and `props` to be related is for the caller to manually specify `T`.  And for what purpose? The return type is `void`, which doesn't depend on `T`.  So the caller has little incentive to even make sure that `T` is used properly.  The signature `run<T extends Record<keyof T, FormField | FormGroup>>(props: T): void;` is probably better from the caller's point of view.

---

Okay, hope that helps give you some direction.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbAAqIPZgM4A8AKgDRRFa54B8UAvFBgJaoDWxZ8SamO+A0hBAdylfNWoBuAFDTQkWAhToxeQcNKi+NelADe0qFADaGKEwB2UVkOwAzcgF0AXOVOOoEBBAsATPFpUUAD8jFCuFhAAbhCIMgC+xjYg9k4ycuDQAGLYiAC2AEoQADbIwEzYFsS0DAZGxgDC5lbJqUQuhm4NHl7APv5QABR4SJYA5lAAPlAARtjYxRDIVtMWAK55M7FTUGt+EHaWEL4768XFO3ggmwsAlCFQOflZTCUnzp1PeS9vAOI4azA0nisksfUQdjQ0AaiGOTGADWQiBOdSg602sQiGy2cU6qCiUSxGNxRi8YAAspVgAALIk4mSkuBgACaS0QdNiCVBFnBkNQ0HgyDyYEW+k6FiFEFcI0Q4wZUFQqFcMLhCKRvi50lQpTwAS+P2KKKghzeugARCAIGAzVB4pIoLJtchdY9ct9Xob-thAfooGMAWBzVAQICbXbZL4IE7Yca9ugKlZespgAQAGrUQadbAzABWUeArmzefQJE6YG0REyeFcejREAA7oMAHQtqLIYprKVQZYgW6uVO24yOaR9qBFVC5XwEGXjMjp2R2OPlSpQRB7aqDctUVxfIqlZdVIjUUdRbBMDXSRcWeMrtcWTfaVzjyfT0YWMZkfUek7TL9-APHmKRgThYIzGt+AQMEmPAPlQZDGH+hqOLc8ogWBJqGgAgogKAgLoADyub5k2yR4IMGH+LcTZ5MgYCDKw9C0BReBJMh9oAPTsa6zzfkOXJAA)

Comment: Ok, but the question is if there a way to extract all the possible conditional types into a single union type.

Comment: Sorry; my answer solves the problem "my run-time function doesn't accept class `FormField` since it doesn't extend `T[keyof T]`, even though `FormField` is a possible type of the `FormRelation Props.`"  I'm afraid I don't understand what "extract all generic conditional type into a single union type" means, exactly.  Perhaps you can update your example to explicitly show what you're trying to convert into what?  I expect the change from `FormRelation<T>` to `Record<string, FormField | FormFieldGroup>` is probably the right path forward for you; if not, I need more details. Good luck again!